# How do I restore an Operations Master domain controller when the password was lost?

Tags: domain-controller, password-recovery

**System:**
A single hosting server using Hyper-V hosts all but one server.
A second stand-alone server acts as the Operations Master domain controller, DC1.  A diagram is at the bottom of this post.

**Situation:**
When all the passwords were last updated, something in the process went wrong; the first time ever this process broke down. The next time an attempt was made to access **any** of the 'password updated' machines, the recorded new password didn't work.  This included the overall administrator password which is what prompted the crisis.  Although the entire system was working, none of the servers could be accessed, including the host.

**Progress to date:** The host server and all of its VMs were easily restored using a very recent backup of the entire system.  There was very little data loss and it seems any critical data may be accessible through other means.  The stand-alone DC1 was disconnected to keep it from automatically updating the restored VM DC2 with the now lost password.  The recovered Hyper-V environment is working fine and all machines have been updated with a new password including the overall administrator password on DC2.  So that's a relief.

**Request for help:**  What would be the best/proper/easiest way to re-introduce the stand-alone DC1 back into the system?

I only ask this to find out if there is a way to avoid rebuilding the stand-alone DC1 from scratch.  I understand I can recapture the FSMO roles to the single remaining DC2 making it the new Operations Master, and then effectively add the rebuilt stand-alone DC1 back into the system.  But if there's an easier way to do things I would like to know about it.

I have been told there is a way to boot a server from something like a USB drive, and then somehow go in and regain the primary account for the machine. Is that really true?  I have been skeptical because I assumed all the security we have in these systems could not be so easily by-passed, so I'd appreciate some insight on this idea.

What happens if I simply reconnect the stand-alone DC1 back into the system?  Would that over-write the existing DC2 with the previous 'lost' password, putting us right back where we were after the disaster?

**Final added question:** Because this is a small startup operation, we don't have a dedicated IT person to make sure every best practice is followed, which is obvious since this problem occurred in the first place.  There is a link on the 'Change a password' screen that says "Create a password reset disk". I'm going to assume by not doing that we made a 'bonehead' mistake.  Does that process create something that would have allowed us to bypass the restore process we're going through right now?

[image]

Comment: You only ever talk about the second domain controller. What about the first DC? Was that part of the servers you restored from backup?

Comment: I updated the post to provide better commentary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nuke DC1. Don't attempt to try and recover it. It's not worth the hassle. Just format, install Windows fresh, and promote to DC.

Since you currently have only 1 DC/DNS server, the only DNS server configured on the DC's NIC should be 127.0.0.1.

Once you get the second DC online, the first DNS setting on the network adapters should be the OTHER DNS server, and the second should be 127.0.0.1. If it was not configured this way previously, then you could have had a replication error that caused your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I did have those settings as you described.  There was a second sandbox network with just a single DC, and it suffered the same password problem (also easily recovered from backups).  I think the password was recorded incorrectly.  So WRT the other questions, am I correct there's no simple 'back door' method to recover a server password, yes?  And would a password reset disk have helped in this situation where the system admin password was lost?

Comment: A password reset disk is for local user accounts, not for domain accounts. What you should have done is performed an authoritative restore of AD when you restored everything. That would have allowed you to reconnect the other DC with no ill effects. As it is now, you should seize the FSMO roles to the remaining DC, destroy the other DC, manually remove it from AD, and build a new DC to take it's place.

Comment: How do you prevent this in the future? Don't change all of the passwords at the same time. (BTW, why are you doing that? This smells of a process problem.) You should have an account with Domain Admin privileges (or password reset privileges at a minimum) available that you don't change the password to at the same time. Because then you could have logged in and fixed the problem.

Comment: @longneck I understand your suggestion and will do that.  Thanks.

Comment: @joeqwerty I actually have the ability to, in reasonably short order, perform the network restoration again.  I'd be willing to try that if I can.  I looked up authoritative restore which says it prevents replication from overwriting data, but it also said it's for objects deleted from AD DS, but I'm assuming from your suggestion it's the replication prevention that I need.  But how do I do an authoritative restore if I can't get into either DC?  And is this a way of forcing DC1 to be over-written by a replication from DC2 if I join DC1 back into the network?